# Getting auth token for dropbox account from accountmanager in android

Tags: android, oauth, dropbox, accountmanager

I am trying to get auth token for a dropbox account configured in device from account manager. I am using

`accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "DROPBOX",null,Hello.this, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);//account"` is dropbox account

I am seeing a Allow/Deny page. I click on Allow, but the callback is not getting invoked at all and i dont get the auth token. I got the authtoken for a google account with this(with a different authtokentype). What i am missing. I am not sure about the `authTokenType` parameter for dropbox. Also are there any other parameter specific for dropbox like the bundle parameter that i am missing. Is this way possible for dropbox?

Check below for the function parameters

```
public AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> getAuthToken (Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler)
```

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

**UPDATE**

1. I assume since we are able to create a dropbox account in android Accounts and Sync(Settings), there must be a dropbox authenticator that has all the functions in AbstractAccountAuthenticator implemented including getAuthToken(). So dropbox should support giving auth token i think.
2. Also dropbox uses oauth1, whereas account manager uses outh 2.0. So is this an issue.Can anyone comment on this?

EDIT:
UPADATE 2 doesnot come into picture at all. I think it is not about oauth1 or 2. Its just whether the service provider has exposed auth through account manager or not as Nikolay pointed. (Coz i did this for twitter that uses oauth1.0)

So is there anyone who has successfully got auth for dropbox via account manager??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Dropbox uses OAuth. Unless they document somewhere that their account provider is able to give you OAuth tokens, what you are trying to do won't work. The 'authToken' parameter is account provider specific, that is why there is no list of values in the API reference. Refer to Dropbox API manuals, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nikolay. Please check the UPDATE. also i dint get it documented anywhere in dropbox api manual.

Comment: It Amay support it, but it may or may not expose it via the AccountManager API. If there is no documentation, there is really no way to find out. As for OAuth2 vs OAuth1, the AccountManager is just an API, the underlying implementation may support anything, including OAuth 1.0.

Comment: "but it may or may not expose it via the AccountManager API". But Nikolay from my update no.1 dont u think that dropbox should have added feature to expose it via the account manager. Also oauth1 vs oauth2, Look at "This lesson demonstrates connecting to a Google server that supports OAuth2. Although Google services are used as an example, the techniques demonstrated will work on any service that correctly supports the OAuth2 protocol." in the page http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html. So any comments again about oauth1 and oauth2

Comment: Not sure what you point is. I may think anything but Dropbox may think otherwise. If they haven't made it public, they either don't expose it (most likely) or don't want people to use it (so that they can change it any time). OAuth2 and one are different and supporting one does not imply supporting the other in any way.

Comment: this has been a long time. but i just wanted to reply. Nikolay is right and i got the auth using dropbox sdk. Cool thing is that it supports single sign on. Thanks Nikolay

Comment: In case anyone is curious, this is still true all the way in 2023.